# Cognito: Amplify user creation in Angular

Tags: angular, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I'm trying to create Cognito user using Amplify in Angular.

Here is the code:

```
const { user } = await Auth.signUp({
   username,
   password,
   attributes: {
      name,
      email,          // optional
      phone_number,   // optional - E.164 number convention
      // other custom attributes 
   }
});
```

This creates the user in Cognito with Account Status: UNCONFIRMED

Where as if we create the user directly in Cognito, its Account Status: FORCE_CHANGE_PASSWORD

We need to set the Account Status: FORCE_CHANGE_PASSWORD

when user is created from Angular. The response is this:

```
CodeDeliveryDetails: {
    AttributeName: "email", DeliveryMedium: "EMAIL", Destination: "t***@d***.com"
},
AttributeName: "email"
DeliveryMedium: "EMAIL"
Destination: "t***@d***.com"
UserConfirmed: false
UserSub: "ab148f86-f66b-4f11-b6f0-510b2a770e48"
```

Answer (score 0):

When new user signup in `aws-cognito` if you turn on `Multi Factor Authentication` the default account status is `UNCONFIRMED`. You have to confirm with `OTP` through `email` or `mobile number` then only the account status will change from `UNCONFIRMED` to `CONFIRMED`

[image]

You can configure `MFA` under `general settings --> MFA and verifications`

Comment: MFA is turned off. I need user to change their password on first login, ie. status to be FORCE_CHANGE_PASSWORD